# Como utilizar a referencia Npgsql para versões de framework menores do que 4.5?

Tags: c#, framework

Bom, fiz uma aplicação pelo Visual Studio 2015, no Windows 7. Porém, a aplicação será utilizada futuramente, também no Windows XP. O problema, é que há uma referência "Npgsql.EntityFramework", que necessita uma versão do NETFramework maior ou igual a 4.5, que não é aceita pelo Windows XP, alguém teria uma sugestão de como resolver tal problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[O suporte ao .NET 4.0 foi derrubado no ano passado (da data desta resposta, no caso, em 2015), na versão 3.0](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/574). Portanto, a última versão que pode ser usada é a [2.2.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/2.2.7).

Se usar o NuGet, não esqueça de travar a versão do pacote no arquivo `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="Npgsql" version="2.2.7" allowedVersions="[2.2.7]" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Então, eu coloquei esse código, mas continuou na mesma.

Comment: O aplicativo está escrito em qual versão do *framework* .NET?

Comment: Quando eu fiz, estava na ultima versão disponível(4.6.1), porém , ao mudar para a 4, aparece o erro falando que o Npgsql é de uma versão maior(4.5+) do que o do target framework (4).

Comment: Sim, então você tem que desinstalar esta versão atual do Npgsql e colocar a 2.2.7.

Comment: Deu certo viu amigo? Muito obrigado, acabei mexendo só hoje e funcionou, foi só baixar a versão 2.2.7 do Npgsql para NET 4.0, como você disse. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @JerryMoon [Veja aqui como funciona o site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Eu que te agradeço.